# error 1242 subquery returns more than 1 row insert sql

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, sql-update, mysql-error-1242

I´m trying to insert into a table but it gives me the same error, and I dont understand why, because as I know, I can insert into a table multiple rows as long as the name columns match.

```
INSERT INTO top_semanal (id_usu, deporte)
SELECT DISTINCT actividades.dueno, actividades.deporte
FROM actividades
INNER JOIN usuario
ON actividades.dueno=usuario.id
WHERE actividades.deporte='Escalada'
ORDER BY usuario.Exp DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

This is the query. And as aditional info, it is very strange because with the same data in my database, sometimes work and sometimes doesn´t. And I need this query to be a trigger so I need this working the 100% of the times.

The goal here is get the 3 of the users with the most experience in the app, filtered by the sports they practice, and insert them into a "weekly top". I have a table "activities" where the users can add their activities, a table users and a table top3. The activities and user is related 1:M

¿Any help, I´m using xampp with mysql?

Edit: there is a trigger when the table is inserted:

```
BEGIN
            UPDATE insignias_usuarios
            SET proceso_Top = proceso_Top + 1
            WHERE id_usu = NEW.id_usu;
            
            IF ((SELECT proceso_Top FROM insignias_usuarios WHERE id_usu=NEW.id_usu AND proceso_Top=1 OR
                proceso_Top=3)IS NOT NULL) THEN
                    UPDATE insignias_usuarios
                    SET nivel_Top = nivel_Top + 1, nivel_Top_Next = nivel_Top_Next + 1
                    WHERE id_usu = NEW.id_usu;  
            ELSEIF((SELECT proceso_Top FROM insignias_usuarios WHERE id_usu=NEW.id_usu AND proceso_Top=10)IS NOT NULL) THEN
                UPDATE insignias_usuarios
                SET nivel_Top = nivel_Top + 1, nivel_Top_Next = 1
                WHERE id_usu = NEW.id_usu;
            END IF;
        END
```

¿May the error be because the trigger is called at the same time instead of 1 by 1 for each insert?

Comment: Any triggers involved?

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: There aren't any sub queries in the published code so the error is likely from a trigger.

Comment: @jarlh Yes, I added the trigger in the edit